# About URL encoding on macOS 10.11

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

The `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` function was deprecated after `10.11`, but `String.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` only available after 10.12.

So, what should I use on macOS 10.11 without warnings?

Answer (score 1):

[`NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1411946-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwit?language=objc) has been present since OS X 10.9. Maybe it's only had that name in Swift since 10.12, and it was available under a different name in 10.9?